# Suggestions for a testing environment on the internet

Tags: testing, deployment, staging

I currently work for a medium size development firm that has 3 main environments - development, testing and staging all on different servers but on the same domain. 
The development and testing regions are not accessible on the internet at all and staging server access is tightly controlled via an ACL and other mechanisms.

Not sure if anyone has had a similar experience but there are certain functionality that can only be tested on servers which are a part of internet. Specifically in our case, we have a bunch of social media plugin implementations (Facebook/Google+/LinkedIn) that cannot be tested unless the code reaches production. These plugins try to scrape information from our websites and inevitably fail so we can never be sure how these plugins will react in production. Additionally, we also don't want developers/testers to post dev/testing links on these external social media sites as this messes up our SEO.
Our internet operations team is averse to the idea of opening up lower testing regions to the internet for security reasons.

Does anyone have any suggestions for an infrastructure that would allow us to push daily builds on a server that is accessible on the internet. Has anyone ever implemented something similar ?

One thought I had is to host another staging environment on a different domain where code would be manually deployed. Having it on a different domain and outside of our network would not affect our SEO rankings and should be OK from security standpoint.

All suggestions are appreciated.